# All mods are equal, but some mods are more equal than others

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[/about](https://english.stackexchange.com/about):

[image: Screenshot]

Dear Jin, this is funny and all, but... but... *BUT*!

(Opera, Chrome, Firefox; Vista.)

Comment: I thought they were making a comment about Russians being inferior to Americans. Imagine my surprise ...

Comment: @Robusto: there goes my theory that it's just the weight of all that copper and silver and gold...

Comment: That takes me to the following question: Does a Kilogram of gold weight more than a Kilogram of copper?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: In any case, a Kilogram is heavier than a kilogram.

Comment: Well, they fixed it, but I think this was an affirmative-action issue from the git-go. Russians equal to Americans ... pffft! ;=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be deployed with the next build.

Comment: You mean the fix will be deployed? ;)

Comment: @MrHen I mean it's live right now.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed the problem was just the sheer number of extra votes that Reg has, weighing his flair down...